# Postgres DB performance for Split vs concatenate when matching

Tags: regex, postgresql, split, concatenation

I have two tables t1 (15.6m rows) t2 (22m rows) both contain a property address which i want to use in a SELECT. However the two tables use different column format to store the address;

```
t1 has c1 with string 'apartment 1 building name' then c2 'street' 
and c3 as 'apartment 1 building name street' 
t2 has c1 with string 'building name' c2 as 'apartment 1' c3 as 'street'
```

To join the two datasets i understand my options to be add new column c4 in t2 which uses `CONCAT` on c2 c1 c3 to match format of c4 in t1. Or use `REGEX SPLIT` on t1 c1 so they follow the format of t2.

Which is the better approach. The final output will be a materialized view with both tables where the addresses match

Comment: Do you have any indexes on these tables and will either option make use of them ? is one question you need to ask yourself.

Comment: I'm new to db but are you suggesting creating an index on one or both that stores the address in a comparable format

Comment: Yes. In this case you will need function based indexe on the column you manipulate and standard indexes on the ones you don't.

Comment: This is going to be sharp learning curve, i'm not sure what a function based index is. I'm currently seeing if a fuzzymatch will work having concatenated one tables address and split the other so they are comparable

Comment: Understanding this will make you a better developer. Current documentation for postgres https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-explain.html